# How to filter Http/https req in network gateway ? without proxy setting

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I want to filter all Http/Https in 192.168.1.1(wifiserver,Linux base) , and without proxy setting in 192.168.1.99(My PC)

```
PC --> WiFi router --> LinuxServer(2 network adapter)  --> WLAN(3G,ADSL, etc...)

192.168.2.99 --> 192.168.2.1 --> 192.168.1.1/201.190.12.13  --> Internet
```

I wish to running a nginx in 192.168.1.1 ,and listern on 9000. Reject or forward http/https to  WLAN.

I try to use iptables,but seem not working:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp –dport 80 -j DNAT –to 192.168.1.1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp –dport 443 -j DNAT –to 192.168.1.1
```

Thank you for any suggestion!!

Answer (score 0):

OK,I find out the way:

```
iptables -t nat -i wlan0 -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.1:8999
iptables -t nat -i wlan0 -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.1:8999
```